# MySQL - Enforcing update of row to ONLY be possible when a certain key is provided

Tags: mysql, sql

This is something I can't seem to find information on.

Let's say I have a table `users`, and for security purposes, I want any SQL query to only executable if a reference to the `id` columns is made.

E.g. this should NOT work:

`UPDATE users SET source="google" WHERE created_time < 20210303;`

The above update statement is syntactically valid, but because it isn't making a reference to the `id` column, it should not be executable.

Only the below would be executable:

`UPDATE users SET source="google" WHERE id in (45,89,318);`

Is there any way to enforce this from the MySQL server's end?

Comment: which MySQL version? Who is doing these queries? Is it something to handle procedurally?

Comment: Mine is mysql 5.7.12, but I'm interested in any general best practice for this. These queries are being executed from changes in the front-end, done by scripts. One of my scripts for a pet project mistakenly updated more rows than it should have because I was careless, and enforcing a requirement like this would have prevented it.

Comment: Define "security purposes"

Comment: Only allow users to run (your own) stored procedures to update the tables.

Comment: In other words only grant them EXECUTE privileges on specific procedures

Comment: [Using Safe-Updates Mode (--safe-updates)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates)

Comment: Thanks @Akina, I've found the safe updates best practice too, but the thing is it doesn't give you flexibility on the column specify. For instance, it would let the script pass if I referenced a `contact_id` column, this would specify the safe-updates criteria.

Comment: That is not possible because your sql statement could also be very reasonable. Your sql server will not "judge" if your use of sql is misguided. you also can not for example block "truncate" oder "delete" statements as a whole..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you can really do what you want is to use a stored procedure, where you pass in the ids and to the update there.  You would set up the security as:

- Turn off updates to the underlying table for all-but-one user.
- Run the stored procedure as the user with permissions to modify the table (using `DEFINER`).

This will be cumbersome because you will need to pass in all the values in the table.

You can come close with safe update mode.  However, that also allows `LIMIT` as well as key comparisons, so that is not sufficient for your purposes.

Note:  This sort of issue is usually handled in another way.  Most users would not have permissions to modify such a table.  Then "special" users who do would be assumed to be more knowledgable and careful about changes.  If the data is sensitive, then the changes would be logged, so it would be (relatively) easy to undo changes that have been made.